# Change group text in dropzone in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm working with dynamic columns, so I need to keep track of an ID for every column.

So I'm using the `field` property for my ID and the `name` property for my column name. (The icons in the header are done with the `headerTemplate` property)

The grid looks fine without grouping (see picture)

[image: Without grouping]

But when I start grouping, the grid uses the column `name` property to show the grouped column (Here it is FN1). Normally it shows also the `field` property in the group template, but I was able to use the `groupTemplate` property to show the the name I want.

But is it possible to change the appearance of the field in the drop zone? Now there is 'FN1' but can I change it so it shows 'abc'?
[image: With grouping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text shown in the drop zone is equal to `title` property in the column setting (if title is not declared it takes the value from `field` property). So you should use `title` to set the text that you want. Eg.

```
columns: [{
    field: "ContactName",
    title: "Group1",
    headerTemplate: "Contact Name HT"
}],
```

It will show:

- data from `ContactName` field from the dataSource in the column
- "Contact Name HT" in the column header
- "Group1" in drop zone

If you still have a problem with this reproduce it in [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/IseME) and share your link to it.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. I had a lot of properties on my column, but I forgot the title prop..